# Why is a derived constructor forced to call a base constructor in C++?

Tags: c++, constructor, base-class

Why is a derived class constructor forced to call a base class constructor in C++ (either implicitly or explicitly)?

For example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct B1 {
    B1() { std::cout << "B1"; }
};

struct B2 {
    B2(int x) { std::cout << "B2"; }
};

struct D1: B1 {
    D1() { std::cout << "D1"; }  // implicitly calls B1::B1
};

struct D2: B2 {
    D2(int x): B2(x) { std::cout << "D2"; }  // explicitly calls B2::B2
};

int main() {
    D1 d1 {};  // prints B1D1
    D2 d2 {5};  // prints B2D2
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's just like inheritance in [Python](https://thepythonguru.com/python-inheritance-and-polymorphism/), except the derived class has to call the base class constructor explicitly `super().__init__()` whereas C++ the base class constructor is called implicitly when not called explicitly.

Comment: @Eljay This exception makes a whole difference. I am realizing that Python by omitting this base constructor call requirement at compile-time can be a source of run-time errors (AttributeError).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A derived class is going to inherit the base class, which means that the functions of the base class need to be used in this derived class. Otherwise the inheritance becomes meaningless.

If the constructor of the base class is not called, the member functions of the base class may not work.

Answer (score 2):

One of the staples of C++ is the importance of deterministic initialization and deinitialization for user defined types. It's arguably the most compelling feature of the language.

So the compiler is made to enforce the initialization and deinitialization whenever it can. C++ will not let us get a half-baked object easily. That's a good thing when maintaining class invariants. We want the compiler's help to ensure those are maintained.

Other languages (such as Python, where initialization of bases needs to be explicit) may choose other design guidelines, but C++ follows its own.

Comment: Is `deinitialization` common terminology? I haven't seen that before.

Comment: Maybe Python does not perform implicit initialisation because its philosophy is "explicit is better than explicit". But it could be done, even with the `super` class that allows [*cooperative multiple inheritance*](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) which requires 1) a `super().__init__` call in each constructor in the inheritance graph, 2) matching caller arguments and callee parameters (by having each `__init__` constructor taking the keyword parameters that it uses and a variadic keyword argument that it forwards to the `super().__init__` base constructor).

Comment: @cigien - I've seen it often enough. It's also present in several computing-related dictionaries. Another popular term to complement initialization is "finalization".

Comment: @Maggyero - Yes, "explicit is better than implicit" is one tennant of Python that probably contributed. It's also not a terrible idea for a dynamically typed language IMO. But C++ is a different beast.

Answer (score 0):

Derived class inherits all members of the base class. When you create an instance of a derived class, base class constructor is called to initialize respective members.